# Powerpoint / Excel VBA Formatting multiple duplicate slides / selecting images / mouse click

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Essentially I have around 90 slides that all have the same format of 5 images pasted from an excel sheet through a different macro and I'd like to have them moved around to obviously tidy up the slides.
I have macros to move all of the objects to the right places and crop one of them.

The only issue I have is how to get the code to select the correct image.
My thoughts were to have the mouse click in certain locations. I have managed to get a macro tomove the mouse to the correct position but it does not click / select the image in that location properly.

It would be easier to select the images possibly by name, I am unsure how to do this and also a few of the images have the same object names of 'image1' 'image2' so I'm unsure if that would work. If anyone has any suggestions or would like more details :)

Comment: By name is almost certainly better. Assuming a reference to the current slide in the variable oSld, you could do e.g. oSld.Shapes("image1").Left = 123 and so on.

Comment: What distinguishes the images from each other on a slide? Are they in a particular position? Are they stacked in a particular order? You can use whatever difference they have to code the final position.

Comment: Why not automate with python-pptx? (My tool built on that enforces standardised positioning. This response is NOT an advert for that tool, which is why I haven't named it.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments :)
What I ended up doing was adjusting the code in Excel to pick the ranges of the tables and paste them separately into the ppt and there I could set size and location following the paste code. The original paste code was some type of loop that was not written by me.

I attempted by name but there were two items named image1, so I figured that would cause more issues

I agree that using Python would be more efficient and I’m looking into that for similar tasks in the future.
Thanks :)